# XamlParseException when binding to static resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

There is an example implementation of a custom authorization for WPF on the [Microsoft website](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25726.wpf-implementing-custom-authentication-and-authorization.aspx).

After you add resources in the App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BackgroundStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0" 
                                     EndPoint="0, 0.5" 
                                     SpreadMethod="Reflect">
                    <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Add this resource in any window:

```
<Window x:Class="Authorization_WPF.AdminWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="AdminWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BackgroundStyle}" Text="This window is only accessible for admninistrators..."/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Get an error:

> The first step of processing an exception of type '
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" PresentationFramework.dll
>
> More information: "giving the value for
>   "System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension" threw an exception.": the row
>   number "6" and the position in the string "10".

How to fix it?

Comment: Your code snippets (without any modifications) are running out of the box in Visual Studio 2012. Are you sure you're providing the correct code ?

Comment: If I repeat the code as is, it works perfectly! But if I add in the App.xaml resources and binding them crash bug. I use Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: It's just a guess because I had some kind of same problem: could you try to add a new resource in the App.xaml, compile it and use the style after the first compile. It would be good to know, whether you'll have the same issue or not.

Comment: After adding a new resource, the problem disappeared. App works great, can use both resources.

Answer (score 1):

remove comments near your references in App.xaml:

> .... xaml/presentation This link is external to TechNet Wiki. It will open in a new window. "
>
> ... 2006/xaml This link is external to TechNet Wiki. It will open in a new window. "

Must be:

```
<Application x:Class="Authorization_WPF.AdminWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="AdminWindow.xaml">
```